# How to plot multiple lines with different markers

Tags: matlab

I would like to plot multiple lines with [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) and do it so, that markers would be different in every line. I know that with colours this would be achieved with `ColorSet = hsv(12);`. Is there some as simple as this method for markers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I am not aware of a built-in functionality of [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) to do so, but I do the following. I create my own cell:

```
markers = {'+','o','*','.','x','s','d','^','v','>','<','p','h'}
```

and then access it this way:

```
markers{mod(i,numel(markers))+1}
```

I also created a function, `getMarker`, that does that and that I added to the path of MATLAB so that I can access it in all my scripts.

Comment: This looks very similar as my solution. But thanks for remembering me about the possiblity of making functions.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is possible by just calling plot one time?

Comment: I've asked a question about passing in an array of line styles here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058490/how-do-i-pass-an-array-of-line-specifications-or-styles-to-plot

Answer (score 4):

```
x = linspace(0, 2*pi);
y = cos(bsxfun(@plus, x(1:15:end), x'));
figure
m = {'+','o','*','.','x','s','d','^','v','>','<','p','h'};
set(gca(), 'LineStyleOrder',m, 'ColorOrder',[0 0 0], 'NextPlot','replacechildren')
plot(x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, it works. But, if i change the ColorOrder to [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1] it does not work any more. Do you know why?

Comment: AFAIK you can set either, not both, of LineStyleOrder and ColorOrder.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's a ready made method: it's the LineStyleOrder axis property.  To activate it you have to disable the ColorOrder property, which takes precedence over the former and is activated by default.  You can do as follows:

```
m = {'+','o','*','.','x','s','d','^','v','>','<','p','h'};
set_marker_order = @() set(gca(), ...
    'LineStyleOrder',m, 'ColorOrder',[0 0 0], ...
    'NextPlot','replacechildren');
```

where the `m` values were obtained manually from the output of `help plot`.
Then use it as in this example:

```
x = linspace(0, 2*pi);
y = cos(bsxfun(@plus, x(1:15:end), x'));
figure
set_marker_order()
plot(x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, it works. But, if i change the ColorOrder to [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1] it does not work any more. Do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

The following also helps.

function testfig

```
x=0:0.1:10;
y1=sin(x);
y2=cos(x);
m = ['h','o','*','.','x','s','d','^','v','>','<','p','h'];

plot(x,y1,[m(1)])
hold on;
plot(x,y2,[m(2)])
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using a simple procedure to randomly create new styles for plots. Though it is not really an iteration but someone may find it useful:

```
function [styleString] = GetRandomLineStyleForPlot()
% This function creates the random style for your plot
% Colors iterate over all colors except for white one
  markers = {'+','o','*','.','x','s','d','^','v','>','<','p','h'};
  lineStyles = {'-', '--', ':', '-.'};
  colors = {'y', 'm', 'c', 'r', 'g', 'b', 'k'};
  styleString = strcat(markers(randi(length(markers), 1) ), ...
                lineStyles(randi(length(lineStyles), 1) ), ...
                colors(randi(length(colors), 1) ) );

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, assuming you are using `plot`, is to add the type of line in the command.
Some of the possible options are: `--`,`:`,`-`,`-.`. There also options for the marker type and for the width.

For example this code will generate several lines with different types of markers:

```
x = -pi:.1:pi;
y = sin(x);
z = cos(x);
t = tan(x);
l = x.^2;
figure();
hold on;
plot (x,y,'--g');
plot (x,z,'-.y');
plot (x,t,'-b');
plot (x,l,':r');
hold off;
```

the generated graph is:
[image: The yellow line is hard to spot, but it's there]

for more help go to: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/linespec.html

Comment: Yes, I am using plot and I'm also familiar with this method you described. I however hope there would be some more general approach. I generate my plot in for-loop and set handle to it. I have managed to get right looking solution with table consisting possible markers and then using `set(h,'Marker',markers(j));` and keeping in mind that index j is smaller than markers table's size. But is there any ready build method to do this.